# How to increment a character variable in a loop ~ VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make a loop to print a step like structure in an excel spreadsheet using VBA.

I have to begin from the cell E1 and go till the number entered by the user in a text box. I need to print a string in the cells E1,F2,G3...and so on.

I used the following but it did not work:

```
Dim j As Integer, N As Integer
Dim i As String

N = InputBox("Plese enter the number of Processes", "Enter data", "Enter number here")

i = "E"

For j = 1 To N
    Range(i & j).Value = "Random text"
    i = i + 1
Next j
```

Thanks for the help :)

[I need the output as in this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y24wK.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex)" property that accepts numbers for both row and column indexes that you can increment

```
Dim j As Integer, N As Integer, i As Integer

N = InputBox("Plese enter the number of Processes", "Enter data", "Enter number here")

i = 5

For j = 1 To N
    Cells(j,i).Value = "Random text"
    i = i + 1
Next j
```

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to accept the answer that best suited your needs

Answer (score 2):

Using `Range.Offset` , starting from "E1" and going through the value `N`.

Try the code below:

```
Dim N As Long
Dim i As Long

N = InputBox("Please enter the number of Processes", "Enter data", "Enter number here")

For i = 1 To N
    Range("E1").Offset(i, i).Value = "Random text"
Next i
```

Comment: You're welcome, please mark as answer one of the 2 solutions you got (by clicking the little **V** next to his post)